# There is a some error when i use laravel 6.0 version this code is given below

Tags: php, laravel

I have a code.. but laravel previous version it was not given any error. now how can I solve it thank you

```
  public function storecategory(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'name'=>'required',
    ]);
    $category=new Category();
    $category->name=$request->name;
    $category->slug=str_slug($category->name);
    $category->save();
```

}

This code is given Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\str_slug()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helpers have been moved to a separate package. You have to install it.

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```